# Does it make sense to combine chrt and nice?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling, nice, priority

I want a CPU-intensive process to have the lowest possible impact on other processes. I can use `nice -19` for maximum niceness and `chrt -i 0` to give the process a `SCHED_IDLE` priority.

Which is more effective? Does it make any sense to combine the two like this?

```
chrt -i 0 nice -19 my_command
```

Comment: Isn't the use of control groups an option?

Comment: I do want the process to get lots of CPU time when nothing is else is running. With cgroups its CPU time will always be limited, right?

Comment: `man 7 sched` is your friend :)